# dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate missing project reference

Tags: entity-framework, migration

I'm attempting to generate a migration for EF, with the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -p .\MyProject.csproj --output-dir ./Dal/Migrations
```

The MyProject.csproj project has a dependency to another project in the same solution: MyDependency.csproj.

When I run the command above, I get a FileNotFoundException saying that the file MyDependency.dll was not found.

How can I instruct EF to reference the proper dependencies when attempting to create the migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually copying the binaries of the referenced project to the build output folder of the main project, then launch the EF migration generation command:

```
cp ..\MyDependency\bin\Debug\net5.0\*.* .\bin\Debug\net5.0\
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -p .\MyProject.csproj --output-dir ./Dal/Migrations
```

Still, I wonder if there's a better way to do the job.